Common practice of sending data from client-side to a designated email?
Here' my situation:
I'm developing a spa, which has a form. I would like to send the form data to a designated email.
What are the best practices or common way of doing this?
Is there a aws service that can just receive the data from client, and just send it to the email?
Do i need a backend to handle this, perhaps?
I have experience only in front-end, so please forgive my ignorance.
I did some researching but found nothing conclusive.
What I was thinking of doing was to set up a backend to handle the data from client, and then send it to some aws service that handles this type of things, but no idea what to use.
And then the service would send the data to the email.
Is this the way to go? What's the more secure and free(or less expensive) road to take?
Any advice is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

You can probably send the form to an AWS Lambda function, which can send the email.
Some examples:

How to create a contact form with AWS Lambda backend | blog.jakoblind.no
Create Dynamic Contact Forms for S3 Static Websites Using AWS Lambda, Amazon API Gateway, and Amazon SES | AWS Architecture Blog
Forms to Emails using AWS Lambda + API Gateway + SES - TommyGroshong.com

These days, you could even avoid using API Gateway and just call the Lambda function directly. See: Announcing AWS Lambda Function URLs: Built-in HTTPS Endpoints for Single-Function Microservices | AWS News Blog
Tip: It would probably be best if you could point the Lambda function to an existing email server rather than Amazon SES, because it can be hard to move SES out of sandbox mode and into production.

Thanks for the answer and articles. Taking a look!
